# Postgresql, create xmlelement with namespace

Tags: xml, postgresql

Could you tell me how to create a tag (xmlelement) with namespace? like :

```
<xs:attribute name="id">Some text
     </xs:attribute>
```

Comment: Have you tried just using the `xs:attribute` as name? Like `select xmlelement(name "xs:attribute", xmlattributes('id' as name), 'Some text')`

Comment: thanks, totally forgot about double quotes.

Comment: It seems xml creation functions doesn't treat namespaces in any special way. You just need to use the fully qualified names for element & attribute names (even the `xs:xmlns` attribute works the same way).